# Are events A and B independent in this Venn diagram?

Tags: probability

[image]
The diagram above shows the probabilities of events A, B and C.

The question is are the events A and B independent?

My confusion is *whether to include 0.12(probability of event C)* in the probability of B.

Assuming I do , my working is as follows:

P(A intersection B) = 0.12 from the diagram

P(A) = 0.3 and P(B) = (0.16+0.12+0.12)= 0.40

P(A) x P(B) = 0.3 x 0.40 = 0.12 So the events A and B are independent.

Is this a correct approach? Or should the P(B be equal to 0.28, which makes the events A and B not independent?

Comment: I agree with your computation and conclusion.

Comment: You are correct. Another way to see it is $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{.12}{.4}=0.3=P(A)$.

Comment: Presumably, the calculation of $p(B)$ has the regrettable *overtone of ambiguity*.  Looks like $p(B) = (0.12 + 0.16 + 0.12)$, rather than $(0.12 + 0.16)$.  This inference is *circumstantially* supported by **distrusting the coincidence** that one of the two interpretations leads to the exact denominator needed to conclude that events A and B  are independent.